# Pandas remove rows where cells in certain columns equates to certain values

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon',
                          'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                'speed': [380., 370., 24., None],
                'height': [380., 370., [], None],
                'weight': [380., 370., None, None]})

   animal  speed height  weight
0  Falcon  380.0  380.0   380.0
1  Falcon  370.0  370.0   370.0
2  Parrot   24.0     []     NaN
3  Parrot    NaN   None     NaN
```

I like remove rows where the values in 'height' and 'weight' columns are either NaN/None or [ ].
So far, I can only remove rows where the cells in the columns of interest are NaN/None, by doing this:

```
cols = ['height','weight'] #suppose there are potentially many cols
df2 = df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', subset=cols)

   animal  speed height  weight
0  Falcon  380.0  380.0   380.0
1  Falcon  370.0  370.0   370.0
2  Parrot   24.0     []     NaN
```

But I want the row with the '[ ]' removed as well. Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`df = df[(df.height != []) and (df.weight != [])]`

This code should update the dataframe with the rows where the height and weight columns are not equal to `[]`

Comment: This would not be efficient if there are many columns of interest, although in the toy example I provided there are only 2 columns of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this match all your case but you can use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to expand (empty) list:

```
cols = ['height', 'weight']
m = df[cols].explode(cols).any(axis=1)
out = df[m]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   animal  speed height  weight
0  Falcon  380.0  380.0   380.0
1  Falcon  370.0  370.0   370.0

>>> df[cols].explode(cols)
  height  weight
0  380.0   380.0
1  370.0   370.0
2    NaN     NaN
3   None     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Your column `height` is of type `object`, not float due to having object-like values such as `[]`, so values that aren't `np.nan` will not be filtered out with `dropna` function.

```
animal     object
speed     float64
height     object
weight    float64
```

You can filter out these values with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon', 'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
        'speed': [380., 370., 24., None],
        'height': [380., 370., [], None],
        'weight': [380., 370., None, None]}
)

df = df[~(df['height'].isin([[], None, np.nan]))]
print(df)
```

Note that `~` means the negative case of the inner query.
Output:

```
   animal  speed height  weight
0  Falcon  380.0  380.0   380.0
1  Falcon  370.0  370.0   370.0
```